# Java wait, notify - wait not working?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning work with `Thread` in `Java`. 
I am trying to write a program that will have two threads.
Each thread will write your name in the cycle.
In `Main` run cycle will generate numbers ( 0 , 9 ).
When it generates an odd number, wait the thread 1 ( even - thread 2 ) .
If a thread will sleep and wake him up .
**The problem is that when I call wait , the program freezes .**
Code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TestClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        myThread one = new myThread("Thread one");
        myThread two = new myThread("Thread two");

        one.start();
        two.start();

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int rnd = random.nextInt(10);
            if (rnd % 2 == 0) {
                synchronized (two) {
                    two.wait(); // first loop - freez
                }
            } else {
                synchronized (one) {
                    one.wait();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

class myThread extends Thread {

    private boolean canIRun = true;
    private final String name;

    myThread(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (canIRun) {
            System.out.println("My name is: " + name);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: a) Don't call `wait()`/`notify()` on `Thread` objects - it's unfortunate, but `Thread` uses its own monitor for other things; b) you're never calling `notify()`; how did you *expect* this to work?

Comment: @JonSkeet how can i call `wait()` for `Thread one`? `notify()` - yes, i know, i will be write ..

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "wait() for Thread one" - you don't wait for a thread, you wait for a monitor to be notified. If you just want to wait for a thread to complete, you call `join()` instead. It's very unclear what you're actually trying to achieve, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You have three threads in your program, `Main thread` is where the program starts executing by entering the `main()` method. `Main thread` creates two threads namely **Thread One** and **Thread Two**. Thread one and two runs their `run()` method. `Main thread` is running `main()` method. When you call `one.wait()` in `main()` method, it pauses the current thread, which is `Main thread`. **It wont pause `Thread one`**. the same is true for `two.wait()`, it pauses the `Main thread` too. Now the `Main thread` can only resume, if any other thread calls `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on the same object either `one` or `two`, whichever object made it to suspend.

In your program, `Main thread` freezes, but the other two thread executes continuously until the program is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create an answer that re-broadcasts @jonskeet's comment above:

**Do not call wait() or notify() on Thread objects - it's unfortunate, but Thread uses its own monitor for other things.**

I have found this out several times the hard way in classes that extend **Thread** or implement **Runnable** that were hung because of synchronized(this).  Since finding this question, I have searched many times and in nowhere have I found any warning to not do this.  And if you have a fast, idle computer, you will probably never find this in testing.

Perhaps someone with better google-foo can find the documentation.  If so, please comment or amend this answer.

wait notify threads synchronized this hung thread